# Autolayout looks different with each screen size

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a custom UICollectionViewCell.
I gave the Cell itself a height and width of the screen itself:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

So there's no fixed number that can cause that.
My custom cell contains 3 UILabels and 3 UIImageviews. 
I put 2 labels and 2 images in a stack, and the other 2 in a stack, and than put 2 of the stacks in a stack.
this is the code:

```
    func setupStacks(){
    dislikeImage.frame.size.width = likeImage.frame.width
    dislikeImage.frame.size.height = likeImage.frame.height

    let likesStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likeImage, numberOfLikes, dislikeImage, numberOfDislikes])
    likesStackView.axis = .horizontal
    likesStackView.distribution = .fill
    likesStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let titleAndImageStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [postTitle, postImage])
    titleAndImageStack.axis = .vertical
    titleAndImageStack.distribution = .fill
    titleAndImageStack.spacing = 8
    titleAndImageStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleAndImageStack, likesStackView])
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.contentView.addSubview(stack)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        likesStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor),
        likesStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),
        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor),
//            stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 1),
//            stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -1)
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 0.98),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, multiplier: -0.98)
        ])
    }
```

the problem is that it just looks bad on non-iPhone X iphones.
This is a picture for example:
[image]

I tried, but couldn't find the problem and why this is happening.

Edit: to be more clear, I want it to look as close to the iPhone Xs simulator as possible, I tried changing the width, and trailing and leading anchors of the titleAndImage stack, but it didn't work. The thing is, is I change the titleAndImageStack.spacing to be as little as possible, the title is disapearing but the image strechs to the sides, How can I solve that?

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Which one of your screen shots "looks bad" and what exactly is "bad" about it. They both look fine to me.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, the problem is that the "picture" on the iPhone 8 for example, won't strech to the sides, I tried trailing, and changing width etc, none worked. The iPhone Xs picture, is how I want it to look like.

Comment: Well I don't see where you set the stack view's `alignment` to `.fill`. Set it and see if that's any better.

Comment: If you want the picture to be as wide as the device (95%), then you should establish that as a layout constraint. Replace the hard coding of the cell size with Autolayout to ensure the cell size is large enough for the content. (In summary, the problem is you've established a cell size. Instead you need its content to establish its size)

Comment: @AgRizzo thanks, how can I do that?

Comment: Try https://engineering.shopspring.com/dynamic-cell-sizing-in-uicollectionview-fd95f614ef80 and then you can continue to Google for more results

Comment: @AgRizzo thanks, I will take a look at that.

Comment: @AgRizzo I looked at few tutorials, But I don't think this is relevant to my problem. My cell does get the size according to the screen size and it is ok. My problem is that the image in my stack won't strech as much as possible in my cell.

Comment: It sounds like you want "scale to fill" as your UIImageView's contentMode. That should allow it to stretch horizontally but you lose you aspect ratio. If you want it to fill and keep aspect ratio (which will crop the top and bottom), then use "scale aspect fill" with clip to bound = true.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was with the screen aspect ratio. I got if fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the X type iPhones have different aspect ratio from the older iPhones.
I fixed it by changing the cell size according to the screen, not the most elegant way to fix it, but it works.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height
    var width: CGFloat!
    var height: CGFloat!

    //iPhone X and above.
    if screenHeight > 2208{
        width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95
        height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5
    }
    //iPhone Xr
    else if screenHeight == 1792{
        width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.85
        height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.45
    }
    //iPhone 8+ and below
    else{
        width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.85
        height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.55
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```